# how to get the object inside an object?

Tags: java

I am trying to use thread can anyone tell me what is wrong in the following code. I am getting a `NullPointerException` in main.

```
 public class threadtest implements Runnable {

   Thread t;

   public threadtest(String name) {
     Thread t = new Thread(name);
   }

   public void run() {
     for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
       try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
       }
     }
   }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
   threadtest ob = new threadtest("satheesh");
   ob.t.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: The wrong thing is the format of the code.

Comment: First, it's better to use this convention: CamelCase for the class names like ThreadTest

Comment: @Daniel, there were no `<br>` before your edit.

Comment: @Grzegorz - yes there were. I added initially the code, then the br's were there.

Answer (score 5):

In your constructor you declare a local variable called `t` which uses the same name as your field `t`. Simply replace `Thread t` with `this.t` or simple `t` there:

```
public threadtest(String name) {
  this.t=new Thread(name);
}
```

BTW1, it's highly recommended to start class names with capital letters, i.e. `ThreadTest` in your case would be a better name.

BTW2, a decent IDE would spot this mistake for you and drew your attention to this.

Answer (score 0):

Field `Thread t` is never used, `threadtest` itself is a Runnable.

Remove `t`, and call `new Thead(threadtest).start();`
or `java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(threadtest);`

Answer (score 0):

You must pass "this" to the constructor of your thread, if you want that your own runnable gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

hey there! actually, Grzegorz Oledzki pretty much has the right answer, however, there is one more thing that was overlooked-
in your constructor, you still need to pass `this` as a parameter to Thread. because right now, you implemented runnable, but are merely passing the string `name` to the Thread constructor. that won't do anything.

```
public threadtest(String name) {
     t = new Thread(this, name);
}
```